# XCode acting weird with warnings suddenly

Tags: xcode

Since yesterday, my XCode has been acting weird. Every time I change anything in a line of code, about 10 errors would appear above where I am changing the code. Then when I click build, everything is okay.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Here's an example:

[Everything is fine, no build errors or warnings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NMpt.png)

[I press enter twice, and this happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO8q2.png)

Comment: Hey bud, I think it's worth you reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then editing your question. For starters you've given us no code so we don't know what could be errenous. If anything, I imagine it's an indentation error which is why no matter what you change something breaks.. But please read the contents of that link and edit/re-ask your question. :)

Comment: have you tried "reboot" already?

Comment: Yes, I have rebooted. I recently ran this command: rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/*, maybe that has something to do with it. I have posted an example.

Comment: 5.1.1, the current stable release.

Comment: hm... not sure, but... it seems to be related with the required header(s). anyways... what do the error messages say and where and how have you imported the related header file?

Comment: oh wait... try this answer at "[How to solve the apple LLVM 5.0 error in xcode 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19478394/2857130)"

Comment: I have already deleted the derived data folder, and ran clean. All the errors are related to calls to the OpenCV Library.

Comment: I figured out the issue. It was because I was importing opencv2 in my .pch file. I put the #include in my .mm file, and all the errors stopped occurring. I'll just leave it in there while I am writing code.

Comment: @ferixhu : depends on where in the `pch` you import it. a bit too soon and it does exactly this. anyways... glad you fixed the issue. i would recommend you post an answer to your question and mark it as the accepted answer.